# How to make a JScrollPane scroll to a position specified by a contents hyperlink from a html file?

Tags: java, html, swing, hyperlink

I'm working on a Help-Window for an application. The Help-file itself is a Word-file that has been converted to an html-file. I'm displaying the html-File in a JEditorPane, which seems to be working fine. The html-File has a contents with Hyperlinks (which do react and jump to the according document in a normal browser). How do I make the JScrollPane scroll to the chapter in the html-File contained in my JEditorPane?

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

public class HTMLDisplayer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        String url = "insert html file with contents hyperlinks here";
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane(url);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        editorPane.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) 
            {
                if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) 
                {
                    // TODO: What do I do here?
                }
            }
        });
        editorPane.setEditable(false);
        editorPane.setFocusable(false);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 1000));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Everything I've tried so far that even remotely works opens the html file in the browser, but I want all of this to be happening in my GUI.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have no idea what I was doing before, but apparently I was looking through the wrong API's and it's literally right at the top of JEditorPane's API... Sorry my bad. But concerning 1), it does actually work now with me just putting the URL into that string. Why shouldn't that be working? This can be closed the solution to this problem is found in JEditorPane's API.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.